# Android Material EditText does not trigger onClick Event

Tags: android

I found a material design widget for android and want to implement EditText with onClick to set the text with DateDialog.

But from this issue of the lib : https://github.com/rey5137/material/issues/144

I can't figure it out, how to set onClick Listener on Material EditText. I have same issue with this lib, and based on my experiment, implementing onFocusChange is not solving the problem

The author just say the EditText component is extended from FrameLayout, and get the id with findviewbyid method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the library is not that good, but to answer your question, seems he means that his widget is something like this

```
<FrameLayout>
    <!-- something else -->
    <EditText></EditText>
</FrameLayout>
```

when you set the onClickListener on the widget, actually you have just set the onClickListener on the `FrameLayout`. When you actually click the on it, the real `EditText` get the touch event and processed it, therefore the touch event is not passed to the `FrameLayout` as it has already been handled.

Comment: in other words, we can't click on this EditText and showing dialog ?

Comment: if you still want to use his library, you have two options to achieve this. 1. extend the class and override [onInterceptTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) 2. find all the children of the FrameLayout which may handle touch event and set the `onClickListener` to override the behaviour

Comment: (1) is obviously the better way. (2) is dirty and not working if it has nested viewgroup

Comment: phew, thanks dude for the insight . . btw I'm gonna use textview component with onClick Listener instead of EditText on this context. Cause I don't have much time to extending, but I really appreciate it, we can try those method "someday" :lol